# Customising class names in ASP.NET Sprite and Image Optimization framework

Tags: asp.net, css, customization, css-sprites, image-optimization

Is it possible to control the generated CSS class names within the ASP.NET Sprite and Image Optimization Framework?

***Further information:***

I currently have two sprites, one for 16x16 icons and another for 32x32 icons. At present the class names are in the format `.icon-16.[imagename]` and `.icon-32.[imagename]`.

I will be referencing the classes in the markup manually (i.e. not via the framework helpers):

e.g. `class="icon-16 my-image"`.

Is there a way to achieve this with the framework?